# ASP.NET ,equivalent to PHP Print_r Function?

Tags: php, asp.net

PHP Print_r is useful to print out array and dictionary collection.
is asp.net build in this function??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "pretty printing". Google ".NET pprint" you might have some luck.

But really, use the debugger.

Comment: What for times situations where the debugger is not an option? YOu are not asking the question asked!

Comment: If the debugger is not available odds are you are doing it wrong. I don't need you to point out I didn't ask the question, learning to properly solve a problem is as important as getting a quick fix, I appreciate when I'm given advise like this.

Comment: @rgz if you upload it to a hosting provider then you may not be able to use debugger.And sometimes it may work localy but not remotely

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it by JavaScriptSerializer

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(yourObject);
Response.Write("yourObject:" + json + "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such function in the framework base class library. If it is for debugging purposes you could set brake points in the code and analyze the values in your collection. If it is for printing it on the screen you could override the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method for each object. Yet another option would be to serialize the array to XML if this format is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said: you can use the debugger to get a better view if that is what you need.  If you want to show the data in the html you can bind the object to a control, which is a much more powerful and flexible way to handle the output.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no function available in .net as print_r(). But you can use your custom function and print array or `IEnumerable` items in response. For E.g:

```
if (val is IEnumerable)
        {
            var e = val as IEnumerable;
            foreach (var i in e)
            {
                Response.Write(i.ToString() + "<br />");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
string[] weekDays4 = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
foreach (var item in weekDays4)
{
  Response.Write(item.ToString() + " test<br />");
}
```