# Is there a simple way to trace out variable in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net, just wondering if there is a simple way to trace out the variable. rather than set up asp:label and then inject text into it? for example, php have print_r to print out all the array?

Comment: use Immediate Windows in your VS to check value (in Debug time)

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: lol.. `print_r` is so archaic compared to what you have at your disposal in .NET.

Comment: @SonerGönül i am new to asp.net the book just keep doing asp:label to show variable and ect... maybe i should continue to read

Comment: @SimonWhitehead can i have a good example?

Comment: Google for *.NET debug* at the first place...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I am research debug for ASP.net was keep search term like trace varaibles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During debug you can use Watch window where you have to give your variable name and will appear with value.

After you compile your bin, and run under debugger,

Once you hit a break point in the same file, go to Debug ->Windows -> [Watch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks SeeShapr for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

For single items, there is Response.Write(varname) where varname is the var you are trying to check. This will output the value of your var to the screen.

There is no direct equivalent to the PHP print_r command, however. There is a suggestion for how to do it via code at
[ASP.NET ,equivalent to PHP Print_r Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763985/asp-net-equivalent-to-php-print-r-function)

There are also several other suggestions if you put "php print_r asp.net equivalent" in Google.

Comment: You should use debug over printing variable values on screen on the first place

Comment: I agree that is a best practice, but sometimes you want to be quick and dirty. And when you have a development environment that nobody sees, writing to the screen is easier.

Comment: The problem with Response.Write is that the output usually arrives before the `<html>` tag because there is no html to write to before the Render phase completes.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself.

Turn on the debug to true:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

Then click on the debug output

```
Debug.WriteLine("test");
```

[MSDN - Debug.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx)