# How to post js array to vb.net MVC in controller and print its contents?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am new to vb.net MVC.
I am posting 4 arrays from ajax to vb controller.
I want to get those contents printed same as in PHP what we do like `print_r($_POST)`.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
var sellBookData = {
    "bookCondition": JSON.stringify(bookCondition),
    "book_qty": JSON.stringify(book_qty),
    "book_price": JSON.stringify(book_price),
    "book_remark":JSON.stringify(book_remark)
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseurl + "Sell/sellBookInventory",
    data: sellBookData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {....}....
```

in Controller:

```
Function sellBookInventory(sellBookData) As ActionResult
........
Response.Write(Request("sellBookData"))
..........
```

Comment: What values contains `bookCondition, book_qty ` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET ,equivalent to PHP Print\_r Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763985/asp-net-equivalent-to-php-print-r-function)

Comment: Values the array contain are :

bookCondition:["10","8"]
book_qty:["2312","121"]
book_price:["213","21312"]
book_remark:["asdasd","213123"]

Comment: You cannot use `"bookCondition": JSON.stringify(bookCondition),` etc - it needs to be `var sellBookData = { bookCondition: bookCondition, .... }` and then `data: JSON.stringify(sellBookData),` and include `contentType: 'application/json'`. You need to edit you question with the data that `bookCondition` etc contains (not in comments)